# How can I encrypt the swap file under Windows 7?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, swap

Mac OS X has the ability to use "secure virtual memory", meaning that anything from RAM that is swapped out to disk is encrypted. This improves security by making sure no passwords / keys are ever written to disk unencrypted. [It's enabled by default since 10.8](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11128?viewlocale=en_US)

Is there something similar under Windows? (Specifically windows 7) Is it possible to encrypt the Windows page file (swap / virtual memory) under Windows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Starting with Windows Vista and WIndows Server 2008 this feature is now available. In an administrator command prompt (Start > All Programs > Accessories > *right click* Command Prompt *and* Run As Administrator) the following command:

```
fsutil behavior set encryptpagingfile 1
```

Will enable windows pagefile encryption. A reboot is required for this to take effect. [According to InfoWorld](http://www.infoworld.com/d/security-central/windows-7-security-primer-part-four-128?page=0,1), this is very secure, using one-time keys just like Mac OS X "Secure Virtual Memory":

> In Windows 7 (and Vista), you can enable pagefile encryption. But even better: There is no key management. Windows creates and deletes the encryption keys as needed and there isn't a chance the user can "lose" the key or require a recovery event. It's crypto security at its best.

To simply check if pagefile encryption is enabled, use the command:

```
fsutil behavior query encryptpagingfile
```

To disable it, the command is:

```
fsutil behavior set encryptpagingfile 0
```

followed by a reboot. Note that this method of pagefile encryption requires that the volume on which the windows page file resides be NTFS formated.

Comment: I had a non-standard pagefile configuration (having it on a partition not associated with a drive letter but mounted as a directory inside my other partition), that I made by directly editing the registry. That was working fine, but enabling encryption in this particular situation caused the system to restart at boot (actually because of a SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION blue screen). I used the registry editor (regedit at command prompt in the windows recovery utility) to mount the SYSTEM hive and disable encryption (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem\EncryptPagingFile = 0).